# C# MongoDb BsonDocument Agregar subdocumento con un nuevo ObjectId

Tags: c#, mongodb

### Partiendo de:

#### Clase que agrega un subdocumento a un documento

```
   public Boolean AggregateSubdocument(string nameCollection, string idDocument, string nameSubdocument, object subdomcument)
    {

        BsonDocument newSubdocument = BsonDocument.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(subdomcument));
        newSubdocument.Remove("Id");
        var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(nameCollection);
        var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", ObjectId.Parse(idDocument));
        var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Push(nameSubdocument, newSubdocument);
        var result = collection.UpdateOne(filter, update);
        if (result.IsModifiedCountAvailable)
        {
            if (result.ModifiedCount == 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

#### Me genera  lo siguiente:

Dentro de mi  colección

```
  "_id" : ObjectId("59f3540a91bfb21a40121a17"),
    "Nombre" : "el  conde dracula",
    "Viviendas" : "1",
    "Estado" : "condesco",
    "Ciudad" : "transilvania",
    "Colonia" : "conde",
    "Cp" : "20398",
    "Direccion" : "tres tumbas, calle murcielago",
    "Correo" : "conde@dracula.org",
    "Referencia" : "cerca de los hombres lobo",
    "Usuarios" : [
            {
                    "Nick" : "59f3540a91bfb21a40121a17",
                    "Nombre" : "sr. dracula",
                    "Tipo" : "administrador",
                    "Email" : "dracula@vampiro.org",
                    "Password" : "jy2u9wcwofklm8rpef38xikun5dvffgwjsnbuq4btepfwlymoxyl0b8dcyftzwgt",
                    "Estado" : "codesco",
                    "Ciudad" : "transilvania",
                    "Cp" : "209",
                    "Direccion" : "calle vampiro, s/n"
            },
            {
                    "Nick" : "59f3540a91bfb21a40121a17",
                    "Nombre" : "usuario dos",
                    "Tipo" : "normal",
                    "Email" : "test@dos.org",
                    "Password" : "zlzf8tmd0hbjeeahx+ucqbrehiycatqnkhqexcrkdeyo7np0kp/ot3ek0r9sxqxa",
                    "Estado" : "test",
                    "Ciudad" : "test",
                    "Cp" : "23255",
                    "Direccion" : "test"
            }
    ]
```

Con la línea

```
var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Push(nameSubdocument, newSubdocument);
```

Logro generar un arreglo, en el cual se puede ir agregando n nodos, pero no me genera en cada nodo un `"_id" : ObjectId()`

### Pregunta

Como generar un ObjectID() en cada subdcoleccion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Una solucción

```
var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.AddToSet(nameSubdocument, new BsonDocument(){
            {"_id", ObjectId.GenerateNewId()},
            newSubdocument
        });
```

Creación de nuevo documento

```
new BsonDocument(){}
```

Dentro de las llaves se puden crear "n" elementos para el documento ejemplo

```
new BsonDocument(){
            {"_id", ObjectId.GenerateNewId()},
            {"campo1", "valor1"},
            {"campon", 2}

        }
```

use la variable "newSubdocument", la cual ya trae todos esos n elementos que necesito

Comment: ¿Podrías explicarla para que sea útil para la gente que llegue aquí en el futuro?

Comment: @fedorqui he editado la respuesta a tu petición

Answer (score 1):

```
String _id=ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();
newSubdocument.add(new BsonElement("_id",_id));
```

justo despues de : newSubdocument.Remove("Id");

Espero te sirva, saludos

Comment: Gracias @Rastalovely, Lamentablemente no me funciona, visual lanza el siguiente error:
'BsonDocument' no contiene una definición para 'add' ni se encuentra ningún método de extensión... , pero he encontrado una solución la posteo abajo

Comment: Tu respuesta esta bien, pero add() debe ser Add(), partiendo de ahi cambie un poco  'ObjectId _id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();
            newSubdocument.Add(new BsonElement("_id", _id));', la unica diferencia con mi respuesta es que con esta forma se agrega hasta el _id final del Json

Comment: asi es que bueno haberte ayudado en mi perfil podras encontrar varias preguntas/ respuestas relacionadas Mongo con c#